# Как найти максимальное из трех чисел?

Tags: c#

в программе должно сравниваться три значения, и большее из них должно присваиваться к четвертому значению.

Выглядят ifы примерно так:

```
if (m1 > m2) 
{
    m1 = Mmax;
}
else
{
    m2 = Mmax;
}
if (m2 > m3)
{
    m2 = Mmax;
}
else
{
    m3 = Mmax;
}
if (m3 > m1)
{
    m3 = Mmax;
}
else
{
    m1 = Mmax;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, и надо найти наибольшее из трех, то всё проще, чем кажется

```cs
max = a;
if (b > a)
    max = b;
if (c > max)
    max = c;
```

Или с использованием тернарного оператора

```cs
max = b > a ? b : a;
max = max > c ? max : c;
```

Или с помощью `System.Math`

```cs
max = Math.Max(a, Math.Max(b, c));
```

Или с помощью `System.Linq`

```cs
max = new[] { a, b, c }.Max();
```

Comment: а почему во втором if ("max = a;
if (b > a)
    max = b;
if (c > max)
    max = c;") сравнивается с именно с max?

Comment: @NevazhnoValera а с чем еще сравнивать? Если найдено наибольшее из двух первых, то сравнивать надо третьте с ним. Можно конечно через 3 комбинированных условия решать типа `if (a > b && b > c) max = a;` и так далее, но зачем? :)